# Caption Centered To Image Rather Than Page

Tags: latex, text-alignment

There isn't exactly any code here, since I just want to centre `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`'s captions to the entre of the image included rather than to the centre of the page, if i centre the image to the left, the caption still appears to the centre of the page (without using minipage as that is the only way i know to do it right now).

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image.png}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What I get from compiling it:

[image: What I get from compiling it.]

I want this be centered to the image itself, and not the page, *without using minipage.*

[Here is the source image btw, just some image I found on google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkWvi.png)

Comment: Please make a [mre] that reproduces your off-centre image and shows which class and packages you use

Comment: done that, is there anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach using the `varwidth` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{varwidth}    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but then it aligns the caption to the left, can you just do `\centering` and change that?

Comment: @AmarnathK Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question.  Let me try something else

Comment: @AmarnathK Please see my updated post. The varwidth environment will automatically adapt to the width of your image and thus the caption is centred below it (if the caption is shorter then the image, if it is longer, I would use the caption package to left align it)

Comment: sure, thanks very much!

Comment: do you know where to just post random pdf stuff, because I make a lot of them in my free time, and would like to do something with them

Comment: @AmarnathK Don't really know, might depend on which audience you want to reach. Personally I put stuff I'd like to share on github.